# ClipMenu Action for keeping formatting when pasting from Word

Tags: javascript, html, ms-word

I do a lot of copying from Microsoft Word and pasting into HTML. I'm using ClipMenu for its ability to write a custom action when pasting text.

http://www.clipmenu.com/

I'm writing an action to convert special characters to HTML. The actions are written in Javascript... and I replace all the characters like so:

```
var result =  clipText;
result = result.replace(/é/g,'&eacute;');
result = result.replace(/“/g,'"');
```

and repeat for all special characters and ugly quotes.

But I'm losing bold, underline, and italics which I'd like to keep. Can someone help me to know if those text formatting things are available in the clipboard for me to process using ClipMenu?

I'm 90% finished with this action and it would be great to avoid searching or writing another tool.